# $L^2$ version of the Grönwall Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, measure-theory

Suppose $I=[0,a]$ is an interval, $u \in C^0[0,a]$ and $B>0$ a constant. If $u$ satisfies
$$
u(t)' \leq  B u(t)
$$
then Grönwall Lemma yields
$$
u(t) \leq u(0) \exp(Bt). \quad (*)
$$
Suppose instead $u$ is a smooth function $u:[0,a] \times [c,d]\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying
$$
\int_c^d g(s)\partial_t u(t,s) ds \leq B\int_c^d g(s) u(t,s) ds
$$
for all smooth $g:[c,d] \to  \mathbb{R}$. Can one deduce some similar $L^2$-bound on $u$ in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each fixed $t\in[0,a]$, under your assumptions, it is permissible to set $g(s)=u(t,s)$.
This gives
$$  \int_c^d u(t,s) \partial_t u(t,s) ds \le B \int_c^d u(t,s)^2 ds$$
Note that this can be rewritten as
$$ \partial_t \int_c^d u(t,s)^2 ds \le B \int_c^d u(t,s)^2 ds$$
which is of the previous form (set $v(t)=\int_c^d u(t,s)^2 ds$ to find $v'(t) \le Bv(t)$.)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of this trick. This seems to work because $g$, $u$ are defined on intervals. Do you think a similar trick can be used if instead the $g$'s is defined on some more general set, for example for if the inequality holds for exmplae if the inequality holds for all smooth $g:\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @sarusa it should work also for arbitrary $\Omega$, there wasn't anything like integration by parts used. We moved the $\partial_t$ out of the integral but you can do this with Lebesgue integrals assuming enough about the functions